# I am creating mysql database dump using mysqldump and java with below code on Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql

```
// Specify the full path to mysqldump
//String mysqldumpPath = "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\bin\\mysqldump.exe";

// Specify the command and its arguments
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
    mysqldumpPath,
    "--user=" + dbUserName,
    "--password=" + dbPassword,
    dbName,
    "--result-file=" + backupDirectoryPath + backupFileName
);

// Redirect standard error to standard output
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);

Process process = processBuilder.start();
int exitCode = process.waitFor();

if (exitCode == 0) {
    MyPrint.print("Backup successful.");
} else {
    MyPrint.print("Backup failed.");
}
```

But I am facing a issue, the code give me correct dump of db with size 2, 3gb without stopping the server, but larger size like 3 or 4 GB it loads for infinite time and I need to stop server. When I stop the server it creates the dump correctly... What can be the issue

So any solutions for this problem or another way to create dump for larger size....???

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you writing a program to create a backup? Just use your favourite task scheduler to run mysqldump (or any other backup tool). You seem to be overcomplicating this task.

Comment: Agree with @Shadow here, unless there is a specific reason you need an entire webserver to do this you should stick with the basics. You can use PowerShell, MSDos Terminal and Windows Scheduler (you shared an Windows OS path). Besides that, assuming you do have a reason other than I wanna try this way, the first thing that comes to mind is timeout but it is weird that it is generating the file after you stop the server.

Comment: @JorgeCampos my guess is that the code runs mysqldump in a completely separate process, which is not terminated when Tomcat stops the http response thread.

Comment: @Shadow yeah that seems feasible for a Windows OS. On *nix the process would die with its parent (tomcat). Though it doesn't explain why it hangs the process **until** it is killed

Comment: Actually I am working for client application he is using my app, Client does not have the accesss of mysql server or database, He just take backup from application and save it system, But if the size of backup is increased, I needt stop the server then works fine,